# replace content in a page php

Tags: php, str-replace, ob-start, ob-get-contents

I have some forbidden words, than are stored in database.

the things I need to do is to replace all of them byt a new words authorized.

I did something like that

```
//Inclusion du fichier à parser
require_once GETCASH_BASE_PATH . '/GESTION/pages_html/index.phtml'; // Layout principal
//Récupération du contenu
$buffer = ob_get_clean();


//Modification du contenu
$mots_interdits = censure();
while ($censure = mysql_fetch_assoc($mots_interdits)):
    $new = str_replace($censure['mot'], $censure['mot2'], $buffer);
endwhile;
//On affiche le nouveau contenu
echo $new;
```

the function is located in an other file

```
/**
 * fonction qui requete la censure
 * @return type
 */
function censure() {
    $query = "SELECT `mot`, `mot2` FROM `censure`";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    return $result;
}
```

The trouble I have is that it replace only one forbidden words, I wish it could replace all words.

anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give the $new value to the buffer after each str_replace, or you will only get the last censuration at the end

```
while ($censure = mysql_fetch_assoc($mots_interdits)):
    $new = str_replace($censure['mot'], $censure['mot2'], $buffer);
    $buffer = $new
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays of words too:

```
$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");

$newphrase = str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $phrase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your str_replace function is using $buffer as input, it does not modify it. You need to make sure as your loop iterates that you are using the current, already modified string as a your input to the str_replace function. Try something like this:

```
$mots_interdits = censure();
while ($censure = mysql_fetch_assoc($mots_interdits)):
    $buffer = str_replace($censure['mot'], $censure['mot2'], $buffer);
endwhile;
```

//On affiche le nouveau contenu
   echo $buffer;

Answer (score -1):

Make use of preg_replace() instead of str_replace(),

```
 preg_replace($censure['mot'], $censure['mot2'], $buffer, 1);
```